# Angularjs - load json file in karma+jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to accomplish a Jasmine test (using Karma) to validate JSON config file. Ideally, my app would simply load a JSON file into app.js, then let me parse through to check for server name.

my file app-config.json :

```
{
"api_url" : "server.loc",
"prefix" : "api",
}
```

my app.js :

```
var config = $.getJSON('/js/config/app-conf.json');

var server, prefix;

config.done(function(data) {
    server = data.api_url;
    prefix = data.prefix;
});
```

my karma-conf.js :

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'jasmine.js',
    'adapter.js',
    'angular.js',
    'angular-resource.js',
    'angular-route.js',
    'angular-translate.js',
    'angular-cookies.js',
    'angular-mocks.js',
    'jquery.min.js',
    'app.js',
    {pattern: 'scripts/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
    {pattern: 'tests/unit/*Spec.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
    {pattern: 'config/app-conf.json', watched: true, included: false, served: true}
],
```

When i start test i get this message in browser console :

GET http:// localhost:9876/js/config/app-conf.json [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

Thinks for help :)

Comment: Use a proxy, add this to your config: `proxies:  {'/config/app-conf.json': 'http://localhost:9876/base/config/app-conf.json'}`

Comment: Tinks @MarcoCl for your help, i add the proxies in my karma-conf but it didn't work for me !!

Comment: it work's now :D i just change url of app-conf.json to /js/config/app-conf.json